# How to adjust a GraphViz cluster's margin?

Tags: charts, graphviz, dot, presentation

I find graphviz cannot independently adjust a cluster's width margin and height margin.

As shown below, the cluster's height margin is obviously less than its width margin.

GraphViz provides [a parameter margin](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:margin) to adjust a cluster's margin. However, it cannot adjust a cluster's width margin only and keep the height margin fixed.

**Is it possible?**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The margin value can be a single value or two values, separated by comma.
From the description (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#d:margin):

> For graphs, this sets x and y margins of canvas, in inches. If the
>   margin is a single double, both margins are set equal to the given
>   value.

An example is also provided at same place:

> For nodes, this attribute specifies space left around the node's
>   label. By default, the value is 0.11,0.055.
>   So, use two values, separated by a comma.

However, there is one caveat: the margin parameter is tricky. It's in **inches** for graphs (and I assume for nodes), but in **points** for clusters!